# how to develop function read sms then restore in future by windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mobile, windows-phone-8.1, sms, smsmanager

My task is write a application that read sms, save to file then restore in future. But i can't find any document related to restore sms. Can we restore sms with window phones.

Comment: some sort of research on our side is appreciated.

last time i checked, Windows phone didin't allow applications to read sms data.

Comment: windows phone 8.1 can read SMS. but i don't see restore function

Comment: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1901813-sms-access-api

so no backup api yet.

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sms-SendReceive-fa02e55e/view/SourceCode

Comment: @DelvinDragon That sample is for Windows 8.1, and not Windows Phone 8.1 which has a more restrictive API set.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone goes not give apps access to SMS messages, other than [drafting and prompting the user to send a message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.smscomposetask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: windows phone 8.1 can read SMS. but i don't see restore function

Comment: What API call are you using to read SMS messages on the phone? (Especially as the whole [`Windows.Devices.Sms` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sms.aspx) is not supported for phone clients.