# Microsoft API to read incoming text message on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a microsoft api to read an incoming message on windows phone 8.1? There are xamarin plugins for sending an sms but non for reading the messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to develop function read sms then restore in future by windows phone 8.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255474/how-to-develop-function-read-sms-then-restore-in-future-by-windows-phone-8-1)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible on WP81 unless you are a mobile oem ( aka tmobile or att ) or a phone manufacturer.